# How to get all of the data from AQL query - NodeJS & ArangoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, cursor, arangodb

I'm passing a query result to an array like this :

```
var someArray = [];

arangodb.query('somequery')
    .then(
        cursor => cursor.all()).then(
            keys => someArray = keys,
            err => console.error('Failed to execute query:', err)
        ).then(function () {
            // do stuff with someArray
        });
```

This approach works, but it doesn't feel right. I'm using `.then` three times. Can this piece of code be rewritten in more efficient and shorter way? I googled it but I couldn't find a good example. Thanks in advance.